# Identify this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I found this tree in Crete, Greece close to the sea, planted next to a building. Since I haven't seen this tree anywhere else in the island, I suppose it was planted by someone. Here are some pictures of it.
[image: Whole tree]

[image: Fruit Close-up]

[image: Fruit Close-up 2]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the distinctive leaf shape and placement of the fruit along the stem that appears to be a [papaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papaya).

If so then the plant should "bleed" [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex) (a milky white fluid) when damaged. You can test this by breaking off a small piece leaf. 
[image: Papaya tree in Kinshasa, DRC]
Image credit: By Max.kit - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=54547062

Comment: Indeed they seem identical. I will break a small piece of leaf tomorrow and I will let you know and accept your answer as correct! Comparing the plant with your photo, mine seem to not be doing so well. Could it be the cold? The temperature varies between 9 and 17 degrees

Comment: Glad I could help! Your plant does look quite damaged, but that could be due to many things including: cold, water stress, nutrient deficiencies, diseases, or pests. ——— If you want to ask a question about that I recommend [gardening.se].